# JS and Ajax: how to dismantle JSON object consist of multiple DB records

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I try to learn JS together with jQuery and Ajax, and until now it was more or less painless, but now I faced myself with some obstacles about getting result from called PHP script, initiated by Ajax. What is my problem here? I have a MySQL table and I wanted to pull some data from JS by Ajax call. I tested my query to check is it correct and make result and with same query I built PHP script. Here is my JS file:

```
        ...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    callphp(12,14); 
    //
    function callphp(par1, par2) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "_ajax2php2.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "po1": par1, "po2":par2 }, 
    success:  function(data, status, jqXHR){
    jss=JSON.stringify(data);
    alert(jss);
    //
    var strBuilder = [];
    for(key in data){
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    strBuilder.push("Key is " + key + ", value is " +data[key] + "\n"); }
    }
    alert(strBuilder.join(""));
    },
    error: function(data) {
    alert( "params error" );
     }
    });
    // end of JS
```

and here is my PHP script:

```
    <?php
    $eol="<br/>";
    $uuu= isset($_POST['po1']) ? $_POST['po1'] : '';  
    $zzz= isset($_POST['po2']) ? $_POST['po2'] : '';  
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","some_password","mydbase");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
     echo "Fail to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"mydbase");
    $query4 = "SELECT * from mytable WHERE uc_id='$uuu' AND pr_id='$zzz' ";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($con, $query4);
    $row4= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result4) > 1) {
    while($row4[]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)) { 
    $data = $row4; }
    }
    else
    {$data=$row4;}
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result4);
    mysqli_close($con);
    //end of php
    ?>
```

and it seems that it works good when PHP query return just one record, if there are 2 or more then I'm unable to "dismantle" JSON object by this JS code, because for example if my query return 3 records, in alert it appears like

```
    Key is 0, value is [object Object]
    Key is 1, value is [object Object]
    Key is name_of_field1, value is 1
    Key is name_of_field2, value is 12
    Key is name_of_field3, value is 2
    Key is name_of_field4, value is 1
    Key is name_of_field5, value is 14
    Key is name_of_field6, value is 2015-09-10
```

and I need to be able to get each particular record fields of each record in order to fill with it some HTML table. How to write this part of code that resolve JSON response consist of two or more records made by PHP? I tried examples I found here but no one met my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Ever consider indenting your code?

Comment: Yes, but I'm in a hurry to write a message, and I was afraid that the additional indent except compulsory by 4, could make a mess. I'm sorry due that.

Comment: The easier you can make your code to read in your question, the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Comment: You're in right, sorry due that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop after the DB query, you are just overwriting the value for `$data` with every iteration.  I would suggest not having different logic for cases with one row in result set vs. more than one row, as this does nothing but add complexity to your code. Just return an array every time and you will be better off.  Your code around the query might look like this:

```
$data = array();
$result4 = mysqli_query($con, $query4);
if($result4) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

This simplifies this section of code and will also simplify the client-side code since now you can write it to simply expect to work with an array of objects in all cases.

This means that in javascript your code might look like (ajax success handler code shown):

```
success:  function(data, status, jqXHR){
    // data is an array, with each array entry holding
    // an object representing one record from DB result set
    var recordCount = data.length;
    console.log(recordCount+' records returned in response.');
    // you can iterate through each row like this
    for(i=0;i<recordCount;i++) {
        // do something with each record
        var record = data[i];
        // in this example, I am just logging each to console
        console.log(record);

        // accessing individual properties could be done like
        console.log(record.name_of_field1);
        console.log(record.name_of_field2);
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

You should get in the habit of using `console.log()` rather than `alert()` or similar for debugging your javascript, as `alert()` actually interrupts your javascript code execution and could introduce problems in debugging more complex javascript (particularly when there are asynchronous activities going on).  Using the javascript console functionalty built into your browser should be fundamental practice for any javascript developer.

Comment: OK Mike, thanks, I implemented your code and now I got in alert:

    Key is 0, value is [object Object]
    Key is 1, value is [object Object]
    Key is 0, value is [object Object]

if query returns 3 records. In meantime I try to solve resulting situation but it won't go.

Comment: @LudusH That is because, in javascript, you have an array of objects, with each object representing one row from the DB result set.  I have updated my example to show how you can work with the result set in javascript. This example just logs each object(row) returned from DB to console.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mike Brant. I printed this page like a tutorial and nailed on my wall. You saved my week, what to say - I owe you beer, coffee... God bless you man!
P.S. Why -1 status of post, I didn't ask anything stupid? I learned from your answer more than JSON web page and other pages together. Fast and practical.

Comment: @LudusH Glad to help. I don't know why the question was downvoted.  As I mentioned in comments above though, people generally expect questions to be as developed and clearly stated/formatted as possible.